# show that $\max(d(x,y),d(y,x))$ verifiy triangular inequality

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(E,\,d')$  be a metric space such that $d'( x,y) =\frac{d( x,y) +d( y,x)}{2}$ with $d$ a function defined in $\displaystyle \times E$ to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ verifying the following :

$\begin{array}{{l}}
\forall x\in E,\ d( x,x) =0\\
\forall x,y\in E,\ d( x,y) =0\Leftrightarrow x=y\\
\forall x,y,z\in E;\ d( x,y) \leqslant d( x,z) +d( z,y)
\end{array}$

show that $\begin{array}[t]{l}
d'':\ E\times E\rightarrow \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathbb{R}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ ( x,y)\rightarrow \ \max( d( x,y) ,d( y,x))
\end{array}$ is a distance in $\displaystyle E$.

To prove the triangle inequality axiom for $d'$ i thought since we have $d'$ I can use the definition of $max(a,b)$ that is
$max(a,b) =\frac{a+b-|b-a|}{2}$ since i can write $max( d( x,y) ,d( y,x)$ in function of $d'( x,y)$.

Comment: Why do you need $\max$ while $d(a,b) = d(b,a)$?

Comment: Is your question about $d'( x,y) =\frac{d( x,y) +d( y,x)}{2}$ or about $d''(x, y) = \max(d(x, y), d(y, x))$?

Comment: You see vivd $d$ is not a distance because it doesn't verify symmetry axiome so the whole exercice is to find a way around and define other distances from this wanna be distance.

Comment: Martin R my question is about $d''$ I included $d'$ here because i thought maybe it will help with solving the $d''$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from triangle inequality verified by $d$: $\begin{cases}d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)\\d(y,x)\le d(y,z)+d(z,x)\end{cases}$

$d'$ is a linear combination, so it is straightforward:

$\begin{align}2\,d'(x,y)
&=d(x,y)+d(y,x)\\
&\le\big(d(x,z)+d(z,y)\big)+\big(d(y,z)+d(z,x)\big)\\
&=\big(d(x,z)+d(z,x)\big)+\big(d(y,z)+d(z,y)\big)\\
&=2d'(x,z)+2d'(y,z)
\end{align}$

For $d''$ this is not much complicated:

Simply use $a\le\max(a,b)$ for any $b$

$\begin{cases}
d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)\le\max(d(x,z),d(z,x))+\max(d(z,y),d(y,z))\\
d(y,x)\le d(y,z)+d(z,x)\le\max(d(y,z),d(z,y))+\max(d(z,x),d(x,z))\end{cases}$

And notice both RHS are in fact the same quantity $d''(x,z)+d''(z,y)$.

Therefore $d''(x,y)=\max\big(d(x,y),d(y,x)\big)\le d''(x,z)+d''(z,y)$